# Quōmodo verba "in my opinion" Latīnē loquī?

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation

In colloquial English (particularly in online discourse) the phrase "in my opinion" (often abbreviated as "imo/IMO") is quite common. I am wondering how one might express this in an idiomatic manner in Latin.

One could take the completely literal approach and simply write:

> *in meā sententīa*, *in sententiā meā*, *meā sententiā*, vel *sententiā meā*

But my gut feeling tells me that the above would either (a) be intelligible to a Roman, but feel unnatural and unidiomatic or (b) be completely unintelligible to a Roman, and perhaps even ungrammatical.

In short: how would one express the English phrase "in my opinion" idiomatically, in Latin?

Comment: Possibly *'ut opinor.'*

Comment: I believe I have actually seen _in mea sententia_ used in this context, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can say "in my opinion":

- *Meā sententiā* (without *in*!) works perfectly well, but you must be careful to distinguish it from *ex mea sententia* or (less common) *de mea sententia*, which both mean "according to my wish." A very common idiom that *always* means "in my opinion" is: ***meā quidem sententiā***. Here are [21 examples](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=mea+quidem+sententia), among which:

  > et qui fugitivis servis indunt compedes,
  > nimis stulte faciunt mea quidem sententia. (Plautus, *Menaechmi* 81)
- As Hugh mentioned, ***ut opinor*** is also common. Behold [187 examples](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23ut+opinor%23), including:

  > a primo, ut opinor, animantium ortu petitur origo summi boni. (Cicero *de Finibus* 2.10)
- Plautus also frequently uses ***meo [quidem] animo***:

  > item genus est lenonium inter homines meo quidem animo
  > ut muscae, culices, cimices pedesque pulicesque (Plautus, *Curculio* 499)
- You also have just paraphrase with several phrases that can be found throughout the corpus: ***ut puto***, ***ut arbitror***, etc. Cicero also repeatedly uses the phrase ***ut mihi videtur***.